# rails: undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass and NoMethodError in DepositsController#create

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

Im using checkbox to calculate amount.but i dont know how to pass the calculated amount to database? 
here is my **view code**:

```
<div> <table cellpadding = "5px" cellspacing = "5px" width = "100%" class="table table-hover">

<tr>
<th>rd</th>
<th>click the value </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 
<%= f.check_box :rd, {:multiple => "true"}, 100, nil %>100
<%= f.check_box :rd, {:multiple => "true"}, 200, nil %>200
<%= f.check_box :rd, {:multiple => "true"}, 400, nil %>400
<%= f.check_box :rd, {:multiple => "true"}, 500, nil %>500
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span id="span"></span>
amount: <span id="usertotal"> </span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){ 
var tot = 0;
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
tot+=parseInt($(this).val());
$('#usertotal').html(tot) 
});
});
</script>
```

**controller code:**

```
def new
@deposit = Deposit.new
end

def create
@deposit = Deposit.new(params[:deposit])
if @deposit.save
flash[:success] = "welocme to rd"
redirect_to deposit_path(@deposit)           
else
flash[:alert] = "fill the values"
render 'new'
end    
end

def show
@deposit = Deposit.find(params[:id])
end
```

while selecting the check box i got the total amount value but its passing value in array type(if i select 100 & 150 it shows 250 in **Amount**(shows in view page) but its passing as 150,250 to controller and showing "undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass" error)
  How to pass a total vale? and im having 2 different column for selecting a value and total amount.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the entire view and relevant controller please

Comment: can you paste the params that are getting passed from form.

Comment: Post your controller code.

Comment: @Stonz2: I'm doing recurring deposit calculation and i used checkbox to select the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to create a form, and send your data in the 'POST way' to your Controller.

Just remind to add this POST action to your route file !